# Ordenar listagem de objeto por relação many-to-many

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

**OBJETIVO: Ordenar uma listagem de entidades eloquent baseado em uma coluna de uma relação many-to-many.**

Para criar um sistema de favoritar posts, criei um tabela favorite_posts que seria a ligação entre a tabela posts e a tabela users.
Essa tabela favorite_posts tem uma coluna id, post_id, user_id, created_at e updated_at.

Essa relação foi criada da seguinte forma:

```
//POSTS MODEL
public function favoritePosts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favorite_posts', 'post_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Para criar essa listagem, estou fazendo a seguinte consulta no repositório que serve a model posts:

```
//POST REPOSITORY
    $posts = $this->model->with([
             'favorite_posts' => function ($return) {
                $return->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id);
          }])->orderBy('favorite_posts.created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Porém, ao fazer isso, o eloquent monta a seguinte query:

```
select * from `posts` order by `favorite_posts`.`created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0
```

Ou seja, não é feito join na tabela favorite_posts, o que gera o seguinte erro:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'favorite_posts.created_at' in 'order clause'
```

O objetivo seria que fosse montado uma query como:

```
    SELECT
    posts.* FROM posts
    INNER JOIN favorite_posts
        ON posts.id=favorite_posts.post_id
WHERE favorite_posts.user_id = 4
ORDER BY favorite_posts.created_at DESC;
```

Eu até consegui fazer funcionar com query builder, mas como tenho muitas relações nessa tabela utilizando o query builder, ela não vem com todos os objetos montados, então não é interessante fazer pelo query builder.

O que preciso é retornar os posts ordenados pela data de criação do último registro inserido em favorite_posts.

Podem me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Você tentou trocar `$this->model->with` por `$this->model->whereHas` ?